# Make awk and get columns

Tags: awk

I have next issue:

Look at the structure information:

```
0   PATRAC_1  False   Normal    Normal  3     Not configure
```

We have seven columns, seven values, so, I need to get that values using awk, at the beginig I use space like separator, so, if I put `print $1`, I get: "0", if I put `print $2`, I get "PATRAC_1", etc.

But when I try to get column 7, I get only: "Not", because space between "not" and "configure"

So, what can I do to solve it?

Comment: Dont use a single space as the delimiter, how did you expect it to work when there is a space in the middle of the fields ?

Comment: You don't have 7 columns. You could cheat and use `read`'s greediness with 7 variables, which would put words 7 and beyond into variable 7.

Comment: The point is that I need to get "Not configure" like a complete value

Comment: You've hit a dead end with awk and spaces. Are you stuck with awk? Can you influence the input before it gets to this point? Do you see the problem?

Comment: No, I can not see it. Could you give me some example? thank you

Comment: awk cannot distinguish between the spaces between the columns and the space between the words in your seventh column. Use another field separator. `0,PATRAC_1,False,Normal,Normal,3,Not configure` `awk -F, ...`, use an exact count of two or more spaces, tabs `\t` or anything else that cannot be part of a single field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, awk considers any sequence of whitespace to be a column separator. It can't guess that you want that 7th column to span until the end of the line including embedded whitespace, you need to tell it.

Since you have variable amounts of whitespace between columns, keep the whitespace-based definition of columns. But instead of using `$7` for the last column, use the text of the line, minus the first six columns.

```
awk '{
    last_column = $0;
    sub(/^[[:blank:]]*([^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+){6}/, "", last_column);
    print last_column;
}'
```

If you have an old version of awk that doesn't support character classes, use `[ \t]` instead of `[[:blank:]]`. If you have an old version of awk that doesn't support braces in regular expressions, make 6 copies of that regexp.

Answer (score 3):

If your data is at fixed columns, you can ask awk to split at those **column widths** by setting `FIELDWIDTHS`. eg:

```
awk '
 BEGIN{ FIELDWIDTHS="4 10 8 10 8 6 99" }
 { printf "1=%s 2=%s 7=%s\n", $1, $2, $7 }
'
```

gives

```
1=0    2=PATRAC_1   7=Not configure
```

Comment: `FIELDWIDTHS` is specific to GNU `awk`.